# Fragments: How to improve code?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have activity contains 2 fragments (TitlesFragment and main_detailFragment):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_titlesFragment"
        class="ru.neverdark.phototools.fragments.TitlesFragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/main_detailFragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

My application contains 5 different fragments for showing in the **main_detailFragment** FrameLayout.

For replace the fragments I wrote function:

```
    /**
     * Replace current fragment to other
     * @param details new fragment object
     * @param index index fragment
     */
    private void replaceFragment(Fragment details, int index) {
        Log.message("Enter");
        boolean isOperationNeed = false;

        switch (index) {
        case Constants.DOF_CHOICE:
            try {
                details = (DofFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.main_detailFragment);
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                Log.message("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            if (details == null) {
                details = new DofFragment();
                isOperationNeed = true;
            }
            break;
        case Constants.EV_CHOICE:
            try {
                details = (EvpairsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.main_detailFragment);
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                Log.message("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            if (details == null) {
                details = new EvpairsFragment();
                isOperationNeed = true;
            }
            break;
        /* .. repeating code for other fragments */
        }

        if (isOperationNeed == true) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.main_detailFragment, details);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

When user click on the item in the TitlesFragment I call function:

```
/**
 * Shows fragment by index
 * @param index fragment index for shown
 */
private void showFragment(int index) {
    Log.message("Enter");

    switch (index) {
    case Constants.DOF_CHOICE:
        replaceFragment(mDofFragment, index);
        break;
    case Constants.EV_CHOICE:
        replaceFragment(mEvFragment, index);
    /* ... */
    }
}
```

On the TitlesFragment

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Log.message("Enter");
    showFragment(position);
}
```

How to I can improve function **replaceFragment**?

In my case I have exception when user change fragment by clicking in the TitlesFragment. I logged the reason, but do not take any action, as in my case, that's normal. But I do not like this code, and I don't understand how to I can improve this.

How to I can rewrite this function for excluding occurrence exceptions?

Comment: I updated main message. Index - clicked position in the TitlesFragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A click on your ListView should show a Fragment. So I assume your constants look like this f.e.

```
public static final int DOF_CHOICE = 0;
```

So you can rewrite the replaceFragment like this:

```
private void replaceFragment(int index) {
    Fragment details = (Fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
               R.id.main_detailFragment);

    switch (index) {
    case Constants.DOF_CHOICE:
        if(!details instanceof DofFragment)
            details = new DofFragment();
        else
            return;
        break;

    case Constants.EV_CHOICE:
        if(!details instanceof EvpairsFragment)
            details = new EvpairsFragment();
        else 
            return;
        break;
    /* .. repeating code for other fragments */
    }

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main_detailFragment, details);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();

}
```

Check the loaded Fragments if it's an instance of your Fragments with the `instanceof` operator. If it's not an instance of it create a new Fragment and replace it. If it's the same instance you don't have to replace it because the Fragment is already shown. I assume that there is already a Fragment loaded otherwise you have to check if `details` is null. I didn't test so don't just copy and paste but you should have the idea now.

Now you can get rid of the showFragment() method.

Btw for such questions you should use the [code review site of stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).